# rails4で存在しないページにアクセスが有った時に特定のページヘリダイレクトしたい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

タイトル通りなのですが、railsで存在しないページにアクセスが有った場合に特定のページヘリダイレクトをかけるにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

ActionControllerに下記のコードを追加してみたのですが、正しく動作しませんでした。

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
def render_404
  render action: "works"
end
```

上記のApplicationControllerで制御する方法以外にも解決する方法などございましたら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rescueする内容にMissingTemplateを追加すればよろしいかと。

```
rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate, with: :render_404
def render_404
 render template: 'errors/error404', status: 404
end
```

後、config/routes.rbにルーティングエラーを捕捉する処理を追加。

```
get '*unmatched_route', to: 'application#render_404'
```

とすればview/errors/error404.html.erbが表示されます。エラー番号に合わせてカスタマイズしたエラーページを表示する方法です。

Comment: ルーティングの設定を施したら無事動作するようになりました。ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m

Answer (score 2):

`redirect_to` を利用します。

```
def render_404
  redirect_to xxx_url
end
```

Comment: `rescue_form...`の箇所は必要になりますよね？どうにも動きません。ログを見てみるとRoutingErrorが表示されています。def render_404内部にloggler.debugで適当な文字列を出力するようにしてみたのですが、ログには表示されないので、どうやらrender_404の関数が呼ばれていない気がします。

Comment: `rescue_from ...` の行が無いと `render_404` の呼び出しが行われないので、必要です。